# J2ME HTTPS Connection Problem: Certificate was issued by an unrecognized entity

Tags: https, java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Certificate was issued by an unrecognized Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666487/certificate-was-issued-by-an-unrecognized-entity)

I am developing a little J2ME application that will read our grades from our university's server. With Desktop Applications, It is fine, I can do it but in J2ME, it always gives me this error, even I use well-known services like HTTPS Google, I still get the same error.

```
        urlConn = (HttpsConnection) Connector.open("https://stars.bilkent.edu.tr/srs/ajax/login.php");
        urlConn.setRequestMethod(HttpsConnection.POST);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
        o = urlConn.openOutputStream();
        // Sending my POST requests to server
        input = urlConn.openDataInputStream();
```

In the last line I always get the error I mentioned above. What should I do about it?

Comment: You should import your server certificate to the WTK in the certificate management area. and make sure it has the same name IP address in CN area when you generate your certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, the problem is with the J2ME Emulator, Works perfect on the phone.